# Type "TypeName" must define one or more fields graphql nest js

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Im getting 3 similar errors from my graphql service

`Type Location must define one or more fields.`

`Type Employee must define one or more fields.`

`Type Project must define one or more fields.`

my location and project type extends from another service. but I couldn't figure out why this happens. the employee service is the one that throws these three errors. I will add my 3 types here.
`"@nestjs/graphql": "^10.0.13", "@apollo/gateway": "^2.0.3",`

Employee

```
@ObjectType()
@Directive('@key(fields: "id")')
export class Employee {
  @Field(() => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field()
  firstName: string;

  @Field()
  lastName: string;

  @Field()
  designation: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  city: string;

  @Field()
  projectId: string;

  @Field()
  locationId: string;

  @Field(() => Project)
  project: Project; //get data from another service via fedaration gateway

  @Field(() => Location)
  location: Location; //get data from another service via fedaration gateway
}
```

Location

```
@ObjectType()
@Directive('@extends')
@Directive('@key(fields: "id")')
export class Location {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @Directive('@external')
  id: string;

  @Field(() => [Employee])
  employees: Employee[];
}
```

Project

```
@ObjectType()
@Directive('@extends')
@Directive('@key(fields: "id")')
export class Project {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @Directive('@external')
  id: string;

  @Field(() => [Employee])
  employees: Employee[];
}
```

Comment: Are you importing the class and field annotations from the correct libraries?

Comment: W.S importing from ` '@nestjs/graphql' packge'`

Answer (score 4):

It appears that there are breaking changes in the latest patch version of `@apollo/subgraph@2.0.3`.  You may need to downgrade to `2.0.2`:

```
npm install @apollo/subgraph@2.0.2
```

Also recommend you pin this version, e.g. make sure the version is explicit, and not `@apollo/subgraph@^2.0.0`

Comment: this also fixed it for me, thank you. this was a hard one to track down! i also realized that i don't need to depend on `@apollo/federation` (corroborated by the npm readme: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apollo/federation)